# Joomla. Вывод материалов в блоге с заголовком, превью-изображением, но без текста

Tags: joomla

Сделал вывод материалов категории с помощью типа пункта меню "Блог категории" и выбрал нужную категорию. Материалы выводятся с заголовком, превью-изображением (которое задается в материале, в вкладке "Изображения и ссылки") и текстом, который уже находится внутри материала. Так вот проблема заключается в том, что я не могу убрать этот текст. Т.е. мне нужно чтобы отображалось только превью-изображение и заголовок материала. При клике на материал, соответственно происходит переход в сам материал, где уже отображается текст и прочее. Пример желаемого - http://www.rostprom61.ru/nashi-raboty.html (не реклама)
Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему с помощью hikashop, вместо обычных материалов вывожу товары в категории. Еще есть такой вариант - вставляем в начале статьи разделитель "подробнее", и после пишем текст. Всё. Блог категории будет показывать только заданное изображение и заголовок.
В настройках материалов можно отключить показ кнопки подробнее...